# Project Array Items as document fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I need to project phone numbers and emails from array and show them as Document Fields.
Something like this:

```
{
Name: "Mac",
Emails: [
{address: 'mac@mac.com', title: '', isMain: true},
{address: 'mac@ism.com', title: '', isMain: false}
],
Phones: [
{number: '6465468794984', title: '', isMain: true},
{number: '6465468794986', title: '', isMain: false}
]
}
```

I need it this way:

```
{
 Name: "Mac",
 Email1: 'mac@mac.com',
 Email2: 'mac@ism.com',
 Phone1: '6465468794984',
 Phone2: '6465468794986
}
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: So, can exists N numbers of emails and you want to get keys `EmailX` and `PhoneX` dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use `$reduce`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      Name: 1,
      result: {$concatArrays: [
          {$reduce: {
              input: "$Emails",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {$concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [{
                      k: {$concat: [
                          "Email",
                          {$toString: {$add: [{$size: "$$value"}, 1]}}
                      ]},
                      v: "$$this.address"
                  }]
              ]}
          }},
          {$reduce: {
              input: "$Phones",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {$concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [{
                      k: {$concat: [
                          "Phone",
                          {$toString: {$add: [{$size: "$$value"}, 1]}}
                      ]},
                      v: "$$this.number"
                  }]
              ]}
          }}
      ]}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [
          {Name: "$Name"},
          {$mergeObjects: {$arrayToObject: "$result"}}
  ]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S_4_oq0tdJ7)

Answer (score 1):

Modify `key` dynamically according to the size of the array not seems to be the best efficient query... I suggests to do it in your code, running [this simple query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j00DsZ4GXsR) you can loop and get `Emails[index]` and `Phones[index]`.

By the way, using only MongoDB I think you can try this one (maybe it is possible to improve):

The trick here is to do a "loop" using `$map` to iterate over the `Emails` or `Phones` size.

- So the map wil be from 0 to emails size, which is `input: {$range: [0, { $size: "$Emails" }]}`.
- Every step will be the "index", setting as `as: "index"`.
- And for every step we want to create and object with structure `{"k":"EmailX", "v":"themail@mail.com}`. And that's why we set `k` value as `$concat` the `"Email"` text and index + 1 using `$add` (i.e. `Email1`, `Email2`, ... `EmailN`).
- Then `v` value is simply the elements at that index. So at this point you have `[{"k":"Email1", "v": "mac@mac.com"}, {"k": "Email2", "v": "mac@ism.com"}, { ... }]`
- And this is done for `Emails` and `Phones` and also is into `$concatArrays` stage to get in a single array all `k` and `v` pairs for emails and phones.
- Next stage is to use [$arrayToObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to transform the pairs `k` and `v` to and object like `{"Email1": "mac@mac.com"}`.
- And last part is using [$replaceRoot](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to get calues at top level, merging the `Name` value and the `result` value which is all emails and phones.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      Name: 1,
      result: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            $map: {
              input: {$range: [0, { $size: "$Emails" }]},
              as: "index",
              in: {
                k: {$concat: ["Email", { $toString: { $add: ["$$index",1]}}]},
                v: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Emails.address","$$index"]}
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: {$range: [0, {$size: "$Phones"}]},
              as: "index",
              in: {
                k: { $concat: ["Phone", {$toString: { $add: [ "$$index", 1]}}]},
                v: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$Phones.number", "$$index" ] }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "Name": 1,
      "result": {
        $map: {
          input: "$result",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [
              [
                {
                  k: "$$item.k",
                  v: "$$item.v"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            "Name": "$Name"
          },
          {
            $mergeObjects: "$result"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lyuMkHgxIa7)

P.S. I've tried to be as clear as possible explaining the query. Also I think it is a better option do the loop into the code not getting the computed result from DB. But that's a dev decision so maybe it's ok for you doing in this way.

Comment: The loop is to be used against only one document, after a match stage. It is more for presentation to internal search interface.